# Does using "for i in range(len(nums))" calculate length of nums for every iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to print every number and index:

```
nums = [3,2,1,5,6,4]

#1st code:
for i in range(len(nums)):
    print(i,nums[i])

#2nd code:
length = len(nums)
for i in range(length):
    print(i,nums[i])
```

Out of these two codes which one is efficient or are they same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples will result in the same byte code, except for the fact that the second option also stores the length in a separate variable. So both are effectively identical and there will be no noticeable impact from using one over the other.

The reason for this is btw. that the iteration target, i.e. `range(len(nums))` or `range(length)` is only executed once at the beginning of your loop. So that code never runs more than once, so it doesn’t matter whether you execute that code *outside* of the for loop syntax, or within.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is do it using `enumerate` function:

```py
nums = [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4]
for index, number in enumerate(nums):
    print(index, number)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CPython language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), it is only computed once (emphasis mine):

> The for statement is used to iterate over the elements of a sequence
> (such as a string, tuple or list) or other iterable object:
>
> for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
> ["else" ":" suite]
>
> **The expression list is evaluated once**; it should yield an iterable
> object. An iterator is created for the result of the expression_list.

Answer (score 1):

You can diassemble and compare yourself:

```
nums = [3,2,1,5,6,4]

# 1st code:
def f1():
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        pass # print(i,nums[i])

#2nd code:
def f2():
    length = len(nums)
    for i in range(length):
        pass # print(i,nums[i])
    
import dis

dis.dis(f1)
dis.dis(f1)
```

And see:

```
# f1  -----
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (nums)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                 2 (to 18)
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  6          16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6 (to 12)
```

versus

```
# f2  -----

  5     >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)       # storing len
             20 RETURN_VALUE                            # in variable
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (nums)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                 2 (to 18)
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  6          16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6 (to 12)

  5     >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Identically (only the storing of len in a variable differs). I commented the printing for ease of demonstration - it is the same in both. So `f2` stores the len in a const in addition to what `f1` does - so no noticeable timewise impact - and not reevaluating `len(nums)` multiple times.